# How to write AverageIf (Not an Empty String) in Google Sheets?

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

I have the answer to this question. However, it took me a few wasted hours of research and work to figure it out. I couldn't find an answer anywhere online, so I thought I'd write out a question and share the answer in the hope of saving someone (who is as dumb as me) some time.

I've been working on a Google Spreadsheet for a while to get attendance counts for a few classes. I have a Google Form where teachers input the attendance for their class. That automatically gets sent to a Form Response spreadsheet. From there I have a few sheets that manipulate the input data, then a summary sheet that shows a table of: classes (rows), dates (columns), and attendance to each class on specific dates. Each cell in the table contains a formula which either returns the attendance count or an empty string. Until data exists for a date and class, that cell contains and empty string. The table works perfectly.

Using the data in this table, **I want** to get average attendance for each class in real time. There are a couple of **problems** though:

1. The table is set out for the whole year, so there are a lot of cells containing empty strings until the end of the year, which mess up the "real time" average
2. Occasionally a class's attendance doesn't get filled in, so there are random cells with empty strings which mess up the average throughout the year

I've **been trying** `AVERAGE`, `IF`, and `AVERAGEIF` functions to figure this out. `AVERAGEIF` seems to be the solution but I can't figure out a criteria that works. `"<>"""` causes a return value of 0 no matter what range I'm trying to average. I've thought that using `ISNUMBER(parameter)` as the criteria, but I don't know what to use as a parameter for it. Not surprisingly, using it without a parameter didn't get me anywhere (`DIV/0` error)

I haven't found Google's Docs editor Help to be super helpful, so I was wondering if anyone might be able to share how to  use `AVERAGEIF(does not contain an empty string)`.

Comment: Did you try just `"<>"` or `"<>" & ""`

Comment: "I have the answer to this question" - that's nice but it's off topic. Please read the google-spreadsheets tag ...

Comment: If you set the datatype for the column, wouldn't this problem disappear?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @David. By the time I was adding tags I was having some computer speed issues and wasn't really paying attention. I saw a few other google spreadsheet questions on the site, so assumed it was fine. Now I know!

Answer (score 13):

`=AVERAGEIF(A1:Z1,"<>")`

`"<>"` on its own means "not equal to an empty string" in Google Sheets.

Comment: @pnuts Yes, I did. It kept including all the blank cells in the calculation as if they were zeroes.

Comment: That's weird, I've just tested the formula on a range that includes blank cells and they were not counted. Maybe you could post a link to the spreadsheet where it occurs so that the problem could be debugged?

Comment: It's weird it deosn't work for me.. `=AVERAGEIF(F2:N2,"<>")` all the cases between F2 and N2 are cells with data validation, based on constantes of another page. Only one is filled, so it should give 1/9 percent

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using:

```
=IF(COUNT(E4:G4);AVERAGE(E4:G4);0)
```

COUNT() returns numbers of cells containing valid numbers : if none, the value will be `0`, so the condition will evaluate to false and return `0` (you can put `""` instead of `0` if you prefer). Otherwise, it will use the result of the AVERAGE function.

Comment: Only thing that really worked for me--and so obvious in retrospect!

Answer (score 2):

To all future viewers, easiest way is `Sum(A1:Z1)/Counta(A2:Z1)`

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Web Applications! You should expand on your answer for it to be really helpful. What does the cells in you example relate to?

Comment: This is the only answer that I could get to work. The downvote by above commenter is really uncalled for. The commenter is asking for context which the question and other answers clearly show. Thanks Sydney!

Comment: One downside to this is that the range has to be specified twice

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered (`DIV/0 error`) when attempting to use `AVERAGEIF` to check for empty string. In my case, I only want to take an average if a text column is non-empty, as the number columns will always be populated in my sheet but are only valid if the text column is populated.

My solution is to use an `IF` function:

```
=IF(A2 <> "", AVERAGE(D2:AF2), "")
```

This is what I'd expect `AVERAGEIF` to do on it's own, but it doesn't.

Comment: Excellent solution! It works!