# ISBLANK function returning unexpected results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I want to show the average of a range if any cell is populated.
However, my formula shows the average only if the first cell is populated.

I'm using the below formula:

`=IF(ARRAYFORMULA(ISBLANK(A2:C2)),"",AVERAGE(A2:C2))`

If A2 is populated, the formula's output is not blank, which is expected.

[image: A2, B2, & C2 are all populated]

[image: Only B2 is blank]

[image: Only C2 is blank]

And if A2:C2 is all blank, the formula's output is blank as expected.

[image: A2:C2 all blank]

However, if A2 is blank while B2 and C2 are populated, the formula's output is blank, which is not what I want:

[image: Only A2 is blank]

How do I get the output of the formula to be blank only if the entire range is blank?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write AverageIf (Not an Empty String) in Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103162/how-to-write-averageif-not-an-empty-string-in-google-sheets)

Comment: Referencing [How to write AverageIf (Not an Empty String) in Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103162/how-to-write-averageif-not-an-empty-string-in-google-sheets), this is the [best answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/135339/196152).

Comment: @tedinoz Thanks for the link! I like the IF(COUNT(),,) solution, it lets me do this without referencing each cell explicitly

Comment: It also has the advantage that it doesn't return `DIV/0 error` when all the cells are blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following

```
=IF(AND(A2="",C2="",B2=""),"",AVERAGE(A2:C2))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`AND`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301)
- [`AVERAGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093615)

Comment: Is this the only way? I have some ranges that are really long - do I really have to explicitly evaluate each cell?

Comment: No. Certainly not. It is just your formula corrected. See the comment on your question. If still in trouble, please give an example of your ranges.

Comment: Why provide an answer to a duplicate question?

Comment: fair enough, it answered the question as I wrote it. I'll accept this answer

Comment: You can use `IF(CONCATENATE(A2,C2) = "", "", AVERAGE(A2:C2))`.

Answer (score 4):

To check if *ALL* cells in range `A2:C2` are blank

`=AND(ARRAYFORMULA(ISBLANK(A2:C2)))`

To check if *ANY* cell in range `A2:C2` is blank

`=OR(ARRAYFORMULA(ISBLANK(A2:C2)))`